# ¿Que significa a & b? En otras paginas aparece la definicion pero no logro entender su funcion

Tags: c++

```
class Graph {
private:
    int n;
    list<int> *adj;

public:
    Graph(int n) {
        this->n = n;
        adj = new list<int>[n];
    }

    int isEulerian() {
        if (!isConnected())
            return 0;
        int odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (adj[i].size() & 1)
                odd++;
        if (odd > 2)
            return 0;
        return (odd)? 1 : 2;
    }
};
```

En la linea donde aparece `adj[i].size() & 1` no entiendo que es lo que hace, no entiendo que es lo que compara.

Comment: `&` es el operador `AND` a nivel de bits. Ej. 2&1 equivale a 10&01=00

Comment: solo cuando size() & 1 de como resultado 1 la condicion es cierta en este caso cuando size() sea impar.

Comment: Quiere decir que `adj[i].size() & 1` es equivalente a decir `adj[i].size() % 2 == 1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El símbolo `&` es el operador de comparación binaria; lo que hace es una operación Y (AND) sobre los datos binarios a su izquierda y a su derecha. Por ejemplo:

```
  101010
&
  111000
--------
  101000
```

¿Qué hace esto en el código que muestras de ejemplo?

```
if (adj[i].size() & 1)
    odd++;
```

Odd en inglés significa [impar](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=es&text=odd), por lo que está contando cuantos `.size()` son impares. Para ello se vale del operador de comparación Y binario, ya que todos los números impares del universo tienen un `1` en el bit de menos peso:

```
| decimal | binario | & 1 |
+---------+---------+-----+
|       1 |       1 |   1 |
|       2 |      10 |   0 |
|       3 |      11 |   1 |
|       4 |     100 |   0 |
|       5 |     101 |   1 |
|       6 |     110 |   0 |
|       7 |     111 |   1 |
|       8 |    1000 |   0 |
```